# Visualizing relations in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

How do I ensure that the texts at the nodes or at the edges stand where they should be rather than running across the figure? I would like it if I can box the nodes.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [black, thick] (0,0)   node {    Ethiopia} -- (4,0)   node {   Egypt} -- (8,4)   node {      South Sudan} -- (4,4)   node {   Sudan}  -- (0,0)  -- (8,4); 
\draw [black, thick] (4, 0) -- (4, 4);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node[below, red, thick] {hostile} (4,0);
\draw[-] (4,0) -- node[below, blue, thick] {friendly} (8,4);
\draw[-] (8,4) -- node[above, red, thick] {hostile} (4,4);
\draw[-] (4,4) -- node[above, blue, thick] {friendly} (0,0);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node[left, blue, thick] {friendly} (8,4);
\draw[-] (4,0) -- node[right, blue, thick] {friendly} (4,4);



\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Relations in January 2020} \label{fig: Relations in 2020}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [black, thick] (0,0)   node {    Ethiopia} -- (4,0)   node {   Egypt} -- (8,4)   node {      South Sudan} -- (4,4)   node {   Sudan}  -- (0,0)  -- (8,4); 
\draw [black, thick] (4, 0) -- (4, 4);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node[below, red, thick] {hostile} (4,0);
\draw[-] (4,0) -- node[below, blue, thick] {friendly} (8,4);
\draw[-] (8,4) -- node[above, blue, thick] {friendly} (4,4);
\draw[-] (4,4) -- node[above, blue, thick] {hostile} (0,0);
\draw[-] (0,0) -- node[left, blue, thick] {unknown} (8,4);
\draw[-] (4,0) -- node[right, blue, thick] {friendly} (4,4);


\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Relations in January 2021} \label{fig: Relations in 2020}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is something like this what you want?

[image]

I'd suggest to place `nodes` (`positioning` library with `on grid` option) and use them as reference to easily drawn the edges instead of absolute coordinates. Using nodes, edges stop drawing at their borders.

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[on grid]
\node[draw] (Ethiopia) {Ethiopia};
\node[draw, right=4cm of Ethiopia] (Egypt) {Egypt};
\node[draw, above=4cm of Egypt] (Sudan) {Sudan};
\node[draw, right=4cm of Sudan] (SSudan) {South Sudan};
\end{scope}
\draw[-] (Ethiopia) edge node[below, red, thick] {hostile} (Egypt)
                         edge node[sloped, above, blue, thick] {friendly} (Sudan)
                         edge node[sloped, above, pos=.25, blue, thick] {friendly} (SSudan);
\draw[-] (Egypt) edge node[above, sloped, near start, blue, thick] {friendly} (Sudan)
                        edge node[below, sloped, blue, thick] {friendly} (SSudan);
\draw[-] (Sudan) edge node[above, red, thick] {hostile} (SSudan);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```